# Is there a way to get the First day of the previous month and Last day of current month?

Tags: mysql

Here I need a function in MySQL where it returns

- Dates
- Starting date of previous month
- Last date of current month.

Answer (score 1):

starting date of previous month

```
select date_format(curdate() - interval 1 month,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
```

last date of current month

```
select date_format(last_day(curdate()),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `NOW()` to get the current date and time. `MONTH()` to get the current month. And using that value, you can get the previous month and the next month. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Last day of current month:

```
select last_day(now())
```

Starting date of previous month:

```
select adddate(subdate(last_day(now()), interval 2 month), 1)
```